# How do I use mutationobserver instead of mutation events?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mutation-observers, mutation-events, stream-graph

I am trying to create my first streamgraph with D3.js.  I am starting with a working example which incorporates a tooltip from code posted on-line, http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136:

[image]

When I copy the `index.html` and `data.csv` files to my PC (Windows 7), I am able to see the streamgraph in a browser (Firefox).  However, I get a JS warning, "**Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.**"

What lines of code correspond to the Mutation Event?  And how should I edit them to use a MutationObserver instead?

I am new to D3 and javascript.  Although I found some discussion of mutation events and MutationObservers on-line, I didn't see any examples that were basic enough for me to understand and apply to my situation.  I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that will need to be changed in the D3 source. As a user (and certainly as a beginner), you don't need to worry about this -- the warning is only relevant to the developers. Feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues?page=1&state=open) about this.

Comment: With all due respect I would like to say that... This answer does not show any light to the question asked. A better explanation or even an example to differentiate both MutationEvent and MutationObserver will be much appreciated.

Comment: There are explanations on the internet that are much better than what I can provide here (e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265032(v=vs.85).aspx)). In the context of D3, this is used all over the place, so the question on how to change them is quite a big one. I tried to give an answer that helps OP, who was concerned about the warning. Do feel free to add another answer though.